# How to import JSON-LD into Virtuoso

Tags: virtuoso, json-ld

I'm using [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) at [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00LCEOGM6).

I want to get [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/) Data using SPARQL query. Because I'm making opendata that is JSON-LD Content-type.

But, I can not import JSON-LD file into Virtuoso Conductor.

So, do you know how to import JSON-LD into Virtuoso?

Answer (score 1):

To import JSON-LD into Virtuoso you need to install the [Virtuoso Sponger Middleware module](http://opldownload.s3.amazonaws.com/uda/vad-packages/7.2/cartridges_dav.vad). Once installed, you can use Sponger pragmas and/or URL patterns to facilitate imports from documents comprised of JSON-LD content.

SPARQL pragma example:

```
define get:soft "replace" 
SELECT * FROM <{JSONLD-DOC-URL}> 
WHERE {?s ?p ?o}.
```

Web Service URL Patterns:

- first time

  ```
  http://{your-virtuoso-instance-cname}/about/html/{JSONLD-DOC-URL}
  ```
- to replace/overwrite data stored in Virtuoso hosted named graph (internal document)

  ```
  http://{your-virtuoso-instance-cname}/about/html/{JSONLD-DOC-URL}?sponger:get=replace
  ```
- to add/append to data already stored in Virtuoso hosted named graph (internal document)

  ```
  http://{your-virtuoso-instance-cname}/about/html/{JSONLD-DOC-URL}?sponger:get=add
  ```

Comment: Thanks!!It was a great help!

Comment: Is there a way to send a JSON-LD string (not url) to Virtuoso ?

Comment: Is it `SELECT * FROM` or `INSERT DATA`? Can I `INSERT INTO <graph>` from a local JSON-LD file?